# dag/walk: vertex "module.instances.aws_instance.my_instance", waiting for: "module.instances.provider.aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Terraform is hanging when I'm doing a plan.

Switching on TF_LOG I see lots of messages like this:

> dag/walk: vertex "module.instances.aws_instance.my_instance", waiting for: "module.instances.provider.aws"

I'm using Terraform 0.9.11.

Any suggestions?

====

The code structure is like this:

`main.tf`

```
    provider "aws" { ... etc
```

`instances/instance_name`

```
    resource "aws_instance" "instance_name" {
```

Comment: do you define `provider "aws" {}` in module `instances`?

Comment: no. outside. updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this format in `main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
   access_key = “aws_access_key_id”
   secret_key = “aws_secret_access_key_id”
   region     = "ap-south-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
   ami               = "${lookup(var.amis,var.region)}"
   count             = "${var.count}"
   ....
}
```

or, you can place your credentials in `variables.tf` file.

Comment: You can also set your credentials in your env (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION). Is region set for the provider (either in env or the provider definition)?